# how do you use a liquibase parameter in an insert statement?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-sql

There is a liquibase parameter in Spring boot, let's say:

```
 spring.liquibase.parameters.val1 = value1
```

I want to use this parameter in a sql file like this:

```
insert into table1 (name, value) values ("nameOfValue", ${val1});
```

unfortunately, the only combination that so far worked was putting 3 single quotes - `'''${val1}'''` (which gives `'value1'`) and `substring` removing  the first and last single quote.

Is there a more clean way of using liquibase parameters in an INSERT statement in SQL changeset files?

Comment: What about `insert into table1 (name, value) values ("nameOfValue", '${val1}');` *note* the quotes around **'${val1}'**

Comment: single quotes did not work for me.

Comment: Please, could you provide the actual use case? What is the parameter you are trying to set? `val1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't have to do anything special to insert a parameter from the properties no matter the chosen format of the changeset.

All of the following will result in valid insert statements.

**SQL changeset**

```sql
--changeset me:2
insert into test1 (id, name) values (1, 'name 1');
insert into test1 (id, name) values (3, '${val1}');
```

**YAML changeset**

```yaml
- changeSet:
    id: 2
    author: me
    changes:
      - sql:
          endDelimiter: ;
          sql: >-
            insert into test1 (id, name) values (1, 'name 1');
            insert into test1 (id, name) values (3, '${val1}');
```

**XML changeset:**

```xml
<changeSet id="2" author="me">
    <sql endDelimiter=";">
        insert into test1 (id, name) values (1, 'name 1');
        insert into test1 (id, name) values (3, '${val1}');
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Have you tried the SQL variant? it did not work for me.

Comment: Yes, I did try all of them.

Comment: How exactly it didn't work, were there any errors in the logs? Try enabling debug by adding `logging.level.liquibase=debug` to your application properties and see if there are any clues.

Comment: if the value of val1 was "actualValue" I got the error: "actualValue is not a column name"

Comment: Do you get this error even while using `'${val1}'` (in single quotes)? Can you post the relevant part of your actual changeset? Also, what version of Spring boot are you using?

Comment: The Liquibase version you use might help too.

Comment: it actually works. I have no idea why it did not work before. 3 devs struggled with it for an hour.

Comment: @Greg Does it work without `--liquibase formatted SQL` in your `.sql` files?

Comment: @Dirk without that no inserts would have been executed at all and there would have been no "actualValue is not a column name" error. Above I posted only the relevant excerpts of changelog examples not the full ones.

Comment: @dekkard If you leave out `--liquibase formatted SQL`  with `insert into test1 (id, name) values (3, '${val1}');` in your `.sql`-file then  _'${val1}'_ is inserted instead of the actual value.

Comment: Ok, you're correct, although in the logs it won't show the actual inserts and says `0 row(s) affected`. Anyway this is not causing the mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your *inserts* are done in a *xxx.sql* file then it is **IMPORTANT** you tell liquibase your SQL is formatted, you can do that by adding
`--liquibase formatted sql` at the top of your file

example: inserts.sql

```sql
--liquibase formatted SQL
--changeset Greg:1
insert into table1 (name, value) values ('nameOfValue', '${val1}');
```

References:

- Example Changelogs: [SQL Format](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html) and [Liquibase Works with Plain Old SQL](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/plain-sql)
- Github demo [liquibase-jpa-parameters](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/liquibase-jpa-parameters)